# How to try catch Image.memory

Tags: image, flutter, dart, type-conversion

This code works for png, jpg, etc. However, it does not work for svg

```
Image.memory(
    bytesData,
);
```

Instead of checking for extensions, I would like to be able to do something like

```
try {
  return Image.memory(
    bytesData,
  );
} catch (_) {
  return SomeAlternativeContainer();
}
```

This always returns the Image.memory

How do I try/catch the bytesData conversion failed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Image.memory has an error builder, so you would do:

```
Image.memory(
   bytes,
   errorBuilder: (_, __, ___) { 
     return SomeOtherWidget();
   }
),
```